# Laravel local.ERROR: Route [en.cinema] not defined

Tags: php, laravel

I have no experience with Laravel, because I am rails developer.
So I trying to help to my friend with him site, but we have this problem

```
[2019-07-17 14:48:04] local.ERROR: Route [en.cinema] not defined. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Route [en.cinema] not defined. at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:372)
[stacktrace]
```

I trying to google, but I have no success.

Also I looking for locales files with English version of site, and I find translation for string "cinema" 
What I do wrong?

Thanks

UPD

routes/web.php

```
            // Set the venues routes for root categories
            foreach (App\Models\Venue::byCategory($category->id)->get() as $venue) {
                Route::get($slug . '/' . $venue->slug, 'VenueController@show')->name($locale.".venue_".$venue->id);
            }

            // Set the venues routes for children categories
            foreach (App\Models\Venue::byRootCategory($category->id)->get() as $venue) {
                Route::get($slug . '/' . $venue->slug, 'VenueController@show')->name($locale.".venue_".$venue->id);
            }
        }

        // Route for happenings
        $happening_permalink = Lang::get('routes.happenings', [], $locale);
        Route::get($happening_permalink, 'happeningController@index')->name($locale.'.happenings');
        Route::get($happening_permalink.'/{slug}', 'happeningController@show')->name($locale.'.happening');

        //Past happenings
        $past_happening_permalink = Lang::get('routes.past-happenings', [], $locale);
        Route::get($past_happening_permalink, 'happeningController@archive')->name($locale.'.past-happenings');

        // Route for homepage
        Route::get('/', 'staticController@show')->name($locale.'.home');
        Route::get('/venues/getmapdata', 'VenueController@map')->name( $locale . '.venues.map' );

        // Route for contact form send
        Route::post('contact_send', 'staticController@contact_send')->name($locale.".contact_send");

    });
}

Route::POST('subscribers/store','subscriberController@store');

Route::prefix('legacy')->group(function () {

    Route::GET('subscribers/create','subscriberController@create');

    Route::GET('importcontest500','legacyCustomerController@importContest500');

    Route::GET('happenings/{happeningid}', 'happeningController@showReservation');

    Route::GET('happenings/{happeningid}/confirm', 'happeningController@storeReservation');

});
```

Comment: please post how is defined your route (web.php), and where you use it(something.blade.php maybe).

Comment: As @Vrian7 stated, show us how you're defining the route on `routes/web.php` and the folder where your view is saved. (`resources/views`)

Comment: I've updated ,my question

Comment: You don't have Route `name($locale.''.cinema)`

Comment: yes but I have no one route similar